# What will be happen if we change SELinux set to Permissive mode

Tags: android-source, selinux

I want to create new service, for that have registered service in SEpolicy.

My service is not running while boot up the device , Because device is SELinux=enforcing mode.

I got some information like, If we will set **androidboot.selinux=permissive** mode then I can able to start new service.

Here I have some doubt , if we will set selinux=permissive . We will loose **security** or Android verified Boot or bypass any security related things.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. If you set SELinux to `permissive`, you disable an important security feature of Android. That's why you use that mode for developing only. What the `permissive` mode will do for you is trace all the allow rules your service is missing.

You would typically proceed like this:

1. Implement your service.
2. Enable SELinux `permissive` mode (see [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#run_in_permissive_mode)).
3. Start your service and check `avc` output for missing `allow` rules or violated `neverallow` rules of your service (see [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate)).
4. Carefully think about security implications and add the required `contexts` and `allow` rules to the system (see [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials)).
5. Enable SELinux `enforcing` mode.
6. Check that your service works and `avc` does not complain anymore.

Comment: Than you very much for your reply.Its very helpful for me.Do you have example to create service steps or document.

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend the official documentation at https://source.android.com/security/selinux.
I added some specific subpages of the documentation to my answer.